# How to debug smb public share not working?

Tags: samba

I'm trying to set up a pulic anonymous user login smb share.
Even though my settings are nearly identical to previous successful setups I've made, I still get permission denied.

Here is the share section in my smb.conf file:

```
[test]
        comment = test
        path = /root/test
        guest ok = yes
        readonly = no
        browsable = yes
        public = yes
```

I've tailed the following files and seen nothing when trying to access the share:

1. /var/log/samba/log.smbd
2. /var/log/samba/log.nmbd
3. /var/log/samba/log.192.168.1.2

Comment: I'm willing to say that is not samba the problem but your firewall.

Comment: It's a turnkey linux LAMP stack installed on a VM. iptables is disabled. Also, smb://192.168.1.12 is browsable and I can see the share, I just can't log into it.

Comment: Check the permissions for the original setup vs the new setup. Even though you have guest ok = yes for the test dir, the files may be restricted to specific users or groups (aka root)

Comment: After it failed the first time, I changed the permissions to 777 recursively but that didn't help. Also, the smbd is run by root (as this is a turnkey machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

Although the entire file structures under `test` directory was with 777 permissions, the directory containing it was with 700. changed it to 755 and it is now working okay.